# User authentication not working with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am writing cucumber features for authentication for an API (Rails 5) that I am building, I am using cookie based authentication along with devise, I am having issues with authenticating the user in cucumber
my authentication.feature file

```
Feature: Authentication

As an existing user
I would like to sign in the app

Background:
  Given the following user exists:
    | id |     email        | password |
    | 1  | user@example.com | 12345678 |

Scenario: Sign in
  When I perform a POST request with email "user@example.com" and password "12345678"
  Then I should get a success response
    """
    {
      "success": true
    }
    """

Scenario: Sign out
  Given I am logged in
  When I perform a DELETE request to sign out endpoint
  Then I should get logged out of the app
```

and here are my step definitions

```
Given(/^the following user exists:$/) do |table|
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: table.hashes.first[:email], password: table.hashes.first[:password])
end

When(/^I perform a POST request with email "([^"]*)" and password "([^"]*)"$/) do |email, password|
  post 'api/v1/sign_in', { email: email, password: password }
end

Then(/^I should get a success response$/) do |json|
  expect(last_json).to be_json_eql(json)
end

When(/^I perform a DELETE request to sign out endpoint$/) do
  delete 'api/v1/sign_out'
end

Then(/^I should get logged out of the app$/) do
  expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

The logout specs are not running because I am getting authentication failed. I have looked in to other examples here but I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: have you checked that your user is being correctly saved? can you add a `puts` to your authentication methods that confirms if you got to them or got through them?

Comment: @TarynEast yes I have found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this, I will need to get the cookie from the sign in response and send it in the delete request.

```
When(/^I perform a DELETE request to sign out endpoint$/) do
  cookie = last_response.headers('Set-Cookie').split(';').first
  delete 'api/v1/sign_out', nil, 'HTTP_COOKIE' => cookie
end
```